# how to load image with pushbutton in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

i have tried to make program in python with qt designer but after convert the .ui to the .py, and i can't open the image.
how to load image in pyqt5 with using a pushbutton as button to open the image and using the python

Comment: The concepts of "load" or "open" an image is incredibly broad, so please clarify what you mean by that. Besides, you should also explain what you tried to achieve what you want and possibly provide a [mre] of those attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.